# How to create a variable that records the change in another variable

Tags: r, time-series

So in time series data typically i want to calculate the change/difference of a variable for example price. Now how can I create this variable in my data frame while adjusting its rows such that the 1st observation of the variable that records the change occurs from the 2nd row of the data frame? For context, I want to fit a linear regression model on the log of the change in an index's price with respect to the book-to-market value in the same period.
**Now I know I can start a loop or may interchange places in the vector of the variable but is there any easy way to do this?**

```
# A tibble: 87 × 13
    Year Index Dividends Riskfree LogEqPrem BookMarket     NTIS DivPrice EarnPrice Inflation logindex
   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  1927 17.7       0.77   0.0317    0.281       0.375  0.0740     -3.13     -2.77  -0.0212      2.87
 2  1928 24.4       0.85   0.0426    0.314       0.260  0.0426     -3.36     -2.87  -0.00979     3.19
 3  1929 21.4       0.97   0.0303   -0.112       0.338  0.166      -3.10     -2.59   0.00183     3.07
 4  1930 15.3       0.98   0.0148   -0.288       0.555  0.132      -2.75     -2.76  -0.0607      2.73
 5  1931  8.12      0.82   0.0241   -0.564       1.17  -0.0110     -2.29     -2.59  -0.0957      2.09
 6  1932  6.89      0.5    0.0004   -0.0946      1.44  -0.00396    -2.62     -2.82  -0.104       1.93
 7  1933 10.1       0.44   0.0029    0.422       0.829  0.00744    -3.13     -3.13   0.00430     2.31
 8  1934  9.5       0.45   0.0023   -0.0173      0.774  0.0220     -3.05     -2.96   0.0201      2.25
 9  1935 13.4       0.47   0.0015    0.379       0.560  0.00972    -3.35     -2.87   0.0296      2.60
10  1936 17.2       0.72   0.0012    0.286       0.459  0.0243     -3.17     -2.82   0.0120
```

**My desired output is the difference in log index here-**

[image]

Comment: So is this the sample input? Are you using all the columns? What's the desired output for this sample input? You can use `diff()` to calculate differences between values in a vector or if you're using `dplyr`, the `lead()` and `lag()` function are helpful for calculating differences. But to me it's not very clear exactly what you want here.

Comment: @MrFlick Does this function like references in excel?

Comment: @MrFlick Actually there is still a problem when I use `diff` it reduces the vector size by the number of `lag` value that is given in the function, so when I try to incorporate that in `mutate` to add a new column that records the change it gives an error because the number of rows doesn't match. Now I can `concatenate` a new value to the vector every time but is there any other method that does all of this?  
Here is the sample that I would have to do to incorporate **`diff`**  
  `df <- df |> mutate(logindex = log(df$Index),change = c(NA,diff(logindex)))`

Comment: If you are going to use dplyr, then use the lag or lead function rather than diff to maintain the column lengths.